# Filter front page posts by category

Tags: categories, frontpage

I have three categories (news, pics, vids), but I have all of them showing up on my front page. I would just like the front page to have the news category (and possibly uncategorized category) to show. What is the best way to do this? Plugin? Or a piece of code on the front page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding this code to `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'ad_filter_categories');
function ad_filter_categories($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_home()) {
        $query->set('category_name','news, uncategorized');
    }
}
```

`category_name` is the slug or the nicename of the category. Add a comma separated list of the categories you wish to include.

Comment: i add this code to my theme > functions.php file but no change detcted

Comment: it doesn't work for me