# Pages with posts filtered by category

Tags: categories, pages

My site has a few categories, such as "business", "techology", "news" etc.

I'd like to display the latest posts from most categories on the front-page, except for a few special ones which I can filter out as described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73849/filter-front-page-posts-by-category).

Is there an easy way to add pages in such a way that they automatically display all recent posts from a given set of categories?

E.g. a "business & technology" page which automatically displays the most recent posts categorized under "business" or "technology"?

Comment: Well, I'm pretty much still a WP n00b, so I've tried adding a new page and realized that pages typically contain static content. Also, if I understand correctly, WP automatically generates category pages / archives (e.g. /category/business) - however, those are 1:1, so I don't think there's a way for them to span more than one category - or is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a menu with category items / sub-items does the job here.